# Xcode 7 - /n vs. /u2028 in Strings within plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, plist

Having a weird issue that I can't seem to figure out. I have a plist that contains strings with line breaks. I'm using the Xcode plist editor. To perform the line break, I pressed option+return within strings where I want them, and it shows up fine in the editor.

The weird behavior:
When I have my app parse these strings, some of the strings will show with \n where I put the break, and other strings will show \u2028 instead. I understand from reading that these are both escapes, but I can't figure out why Xcode gives me one or the other. Is there a way I can force it to give me \n instead of \u2028? I'd rather not have to manually process the strings after-the-fact to change it

example:

"Hello\nWorld!" - I want and sometimes get this...

"Hello\U2028World!" - I don't want and sometimes get this...

Pulling my hair out. Thanks!

edit:
Here's how I'm getting the strings.

In .plist editor:

In the .plist, I have a dictionary. In the dictionary are the strings. They were "created and defined" in the editor.

In code:

```
//Get the config variables

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Variables" ofType:@"plist"];
vars = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *blah = [vars objectForKey:@"someString"];
NSLog(@"%@", blah);
```

Comment: It's very hard for us to know how exactly are you creating your strings. However, in code the best solution is to handle *all* possible new line characters using `[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]`. You don't have to care which character was used to create a new line, just detect them all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, added some info on how I'm accessing the strings. I'll  look into the NSCharacterSet solution, haven't seen that before (newbie, sorry...)